# How am i able to save a picture using OpenCV imwrite to a specific folder

Tags: python, opencv, path

Im back with another probably stupid question!, my new issue is the following:
im trying to save a picture from my webcam into a specific folder using OpenCV imwrite,
its not working obviously here is my code:

```
import cv2 as cv

cam = cv.VideoCapture(0)   
s, img = cam.read()
if s:
    path = r"\imgtest\selfietest.jpg"
    cv.imwrite(path, img)
```

Any suggestions for edits or fixes?, i've tried copying the file using shutil and moving it using the same module, i also tried to use the OS module to move it but it threw an "Access Denied" error so i would prefer to not need to grant the application admin rights every time i launched it thanks in advance!!

((ALSO ASSUME I KNOW NOTHING ABOUT PYTHON))

Comment: try a different path. why does that path start with a backslash? remove the backslash at the beginning. does that `imgtest` directory exist? where does it exist? do you even know where your script runs? look at `os.getcwd()`

Comment: thanks that actually fixed the issue (removing backslash, i thought all directories had to start with backslash unless you were typing the full path as in C:\ etc. ) XD but to answer yes the directory existed, in the local file where the script runs

Answer (score 0):

Use a full path, forward slashes, and r'' to pass a raw path. cv2.imwrite(r"D:/....jpg", img)